# Using Console.ReadLine(); To define a EndPoint Variable?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have been making a network tool for the past couple of days now, and decided to add a TCP Ping Function inside it..
But only one problem is stopping me from doing this.

I need to create a EndPoint Variable from a Console.ReadLine();, Which seems as if it's impossible, or something i haven't came across.
I've been to many articles about Implicitly converting types, But none of them are how i need it to be..

Here is the code i'm working with at the moment.

```
        else if (b4cline[0] == "TCPing")
        {
            Console.Write("Host: ");
            EndPoint ipaddr = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("(0 = infinite) Repeat: ");
            int repeat = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            if (repeat == 0)
            {
                repeat = 999999;
            }

            TCPing(ipaddr);
        }
```

Am I just making a common mistake, Or can this not be done properly?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sockets are different than trying to parse an IP Address, It requires a EndPoint, Not a IPAddress

Comment: He probably meant something like `IPEndPoint ipaddr = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), 0);`